# How do i find the sum of this specific part?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm stuck while trying to do Numerical integrations and I can't understand how to find the sum of this part (pic added).
$$\int_1^3\frac{dx}{x}\cong\frac12\cdot0.2\Bigl[1+2\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{1.4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2.8}\right)}_\text{this}+\frac{1}{3}\Bigr]\cong1.1016.$$

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the MSE community. Where you have seen this formula?

Comment: You just compute each term and add them up.  There are only $9$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

You just do the indicated computation.  With this simple function the inverses have a nice pattern, but for more general integrands they need not.  I put it in a spreadsheet and validated the final answer you give.  You could write it in terms of the harmonic numbers as the terms are $\frac 56, \frac 57, \frac 58 \ldots \frac 5{14}$ but will usually not be able to do so.